# get params from child route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a home component in Angular in which I would like to display a param from a child route

So, if my routing looks like this:

```
{
    path: "home",
    component: HomeViewComponent,
    children: [{ path: ":id", component: ChildComponent }]
},
```

Then in HomeViewComponent I would like to render that :id value, but from where can I access this value. I tried listening for router changes

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationEvent) => {
  if (event instanceof ActivationEnd) {
       this.id = event...........;
  }
});
```

But wherever I look I just don't see it. Any suggestions?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-shtrsg?file=app%2Fapp.routing.module.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the work around to achieve params from child to parent component.
[Stackbliz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-eoneg9?file=app%2Fviews%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts)

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-shtrsg?file=app%2Fapp.routing.module.ts)

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri I have updated my answer please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a component's children through the `activatedRoute` variable. The path to the child is `this.activatedRoute.children[0].url.value` or `this.activatedRoute.children[0].url.subscribe()`. I recommend using the observable option because it is the official way (in the documentation) to access the info you need. You will need an if statement around it to make sure the child component exists before access it.

```
if (this.activatedRoute.children[0]) {
    this.activatedRoute.children[0].url.subscribe(url => {
    this.childId = url[1].path;
});
```

Notes:

- The array index for `children` in your case will always be `0`.
- I updated the routes have multiple children in my demo below, so my `url` index is `1` but in your initial demo it would be `0`.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-te6kx6?file=app%2Fviews%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts)